# Shading issue's with bevel

Tags: modeling, shaders

For a model I used a bevel to get nice and smooth edges, but since the bottom right side is slightly angled* I need to add some extra geometry to maintain a quad only design. But this makes it that the shading gives weird results. Is there any way to fix this?

*I can't get rid of this angle since this is needed in the model

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you might try LoopTools -> Relax on that curved edge.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you make it a bit complicated, why don't you continue your vertical edge loop, like that:

[image]

Comment: Because the angle of the right side of the mesh below the horizontal edge is slightly angled like you can see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aEO5.png This slight angle is unfortunately needed in the mesh :((

Comment: could you please show the reference object?